# I'm trying to make a vendored_frameworks in Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

What I'm looking to do is create a cocoa pod that does not show my implementation of my source code. I was told you could use "s.ios.vendored_frameworks" and embed your framework like how iOS does for it's frameworks. What I want to do is embed my framework, but not make my source files visible and able to edit. What am I doing wrong?

I have a framework that I create via Xcode located here: https://bitbucket.org/nerdgang/ngkitsdk/src

This is my podspec:

```
    Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "NGKitSDK"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "NGKit a SDK for my projects, my version of iOS."
s.homepage     = "https://bitbucket.org/nerdgang/ngkitsdk"

  # ―――  Spec License  ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Licensing your code is important. See http://choosealicense.com for more info.
  #  CocoaPods will detect a license file if there is a named LICENSE*
  #  Popular ones are 'MIT', 'BSD' and 'Apache License, Version 2.0'.
  #

  s.license      = "MIT"
  # s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "FILE_LICENSE" }


  # ――― Author Metadata  ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Specify the authors of the library, with email addresses. Email addresses
  #  of the authors are extracted from the SCM log. E.g. $ git log. CocoaPods also
  #  accepts just a name if you'd rather not provide an email address.
  #
  #  Specify a social_media_url where others can refer to, for example a twitter
  #  profile URL.
  #

  s.author             = { "Havic" => "haveyec@me.com" }
  # Or just: s.author    = "Havic"
  # s.authors            = { "Havic" => "haveyec@me.com" }
  # s.social_media_url   = "http://twitter.com/Havic"

  # ――― Platform Specifics ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  If this Pod runs only on iOS or OS X, then specify the platform and
  #  the deployment target. You can optionally include the target after the platform.
  #

  # s.platform     = :ios
   s.platform     = :ios, "5.0"

  #  When using multiple platforms
  # s.ios.deployment_target = "5.0"
  # s.osx.deployment_target = "10.7"
  # s.watchos.deployment_target = "2.0"
  # s.tvos.deployment_target = "9.0"


  # ――― Source Location ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Specify the location from where the source should be retrieved.
  #  Supports git, hg, bzr, svn and HTTP.
  #

  s.source       = { :git => "https://bitbucket.org/nerdgang/ngkitsdk/src" }
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'NGKitSDK.framework'


  # ――― Source Code ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  CocoaPods is smart about how it includes source code. For source files
  #  giving a folder will include any swift, h, m, mm, c & cpp files.
  #  For header files it will include any header in the folder.
  #  Not including the public_header_files will make all headers public.
  #

  s.source_files  = "NGKitSDK", "Classes/**/*.{h,m}"
  s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"

  # s.public_header_files = "Classes/**/*.h"
```

Comment: I wrote an extensive guide on how to publish a universal, closed-source framework to CocoaPods: https://eladnava.com/publish-a-universal-binary-ios-framework-in-swift-using-cocoapods/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past, that was resolved by setting the s.public_header_files value to point to the header files used in your framework.

Answer (score 0):

In description you pointing that you want to hide your source code but URL in **s.source** points to repo with exactly source code
To hide the sources you need to zip *.framework file upload it somewhere and use this URL for **s.source**