# Can't find CocoaPods vendored framework inside app file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, llvm

I have a pod (**MyPod**) that depends on a vendored framework (**VendoredFramework.framework**) that's about 16MB.

After building the app, I can see the **MyPod** framework living in the same folder as the App. It's just 250KB. My question is: Where is the **VendoredFramework**? I can't find it on the folder, neither inside the app. I also tried to archive or create an IPA, but couldn't find the vendored framework either.

On my main app I have this line on the `xcconfig` file generated by CocoaPods:

`OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -framework "MyPod" -framework "VendoredFramework"`

Here is the podspec:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'MyPod'
  s.version          = '1.2.1'
  s.summary          = ''


  s.description      = ""
                       

  s.homepage         = ''
  s.license          = { :type => 'Proprietary', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { '' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'x', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'
  s.static_framework = true
  
  s.source_files = 'MyPod/Classes/**/*'
  
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'VendoredFramework.framework'
  
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64'
  }
  s.user_target_xcconfig = {
    'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64'
  }
  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [I'm trying to make a vendored_frameworks in Cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155771/im-trying-to-make-a-vendored-frameworks-in-cocoapods) setting s.public_header_files value to point to the header files used in your framework worked.

Comment: Actually, it's already working. I'm trying to find *where* my vendored framework is...